# Fragments não desaparece

Tags: android, android-fragment

Boa noite, estou criando um app para treinar e nele contém menu lateral que cada item do menu chama um **Fragment** só que estou com problema, pois quando clico em um item ele aparece o fragment chamado, mas quando clico no outro item o segundo fragment fica sobreposto ao primeiro, logo não consigo fazer o desaparecimento do primeiro fragment.... Procurei alguma solução na internet, e tem um usúario aqui do forúm que fez a mesma pergunta, tentei seguir o mesmo procedimento mas não consegui... Alguém pode me ajudar?

code xml:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragments"
    android:name="com.nathan.lotogera.lotogera.Fragments.DuplaSena"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

code java:

```
@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

            DuplaSena duplaSena = new DuplaSena();

            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragments, duplaSena, duplaSena.getTag());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {
            Quina quina = new Quina();

            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragments, quina, quina.getTag());
            fragmentTransaction.commit();


        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obrigado....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenta trocar o seu XML por:

```
<FrameLayout
       android:id="@+id/fragments"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

O elemento `fragment` no XML é para carregar um único fragmento. Para substituir fragmentos, tem que usar outro container, como esse que coloquei acima.